# Angular / Web API unable to communicate on endpoint

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm running into an issue where Angular is unable to make a successful request on 2 of 3 endpoints but I have confirmed all work with postman and that the proxy is successfully routing the calls. Chrome - Network tab shows "blocked:other" and output of "ng serve" doesn't indicate anything in regards to proxy. Is there an issue with my angular service and/or server side controller?

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AffiliationController : ControllerBase
{
    public AffiliationController(
        IQueryHandler<GetAffiliationsQuery, IQueryable<Affiliation>> getAffiliationsQuery,
        ICommandHandler<ToggleAffiliationExclusionCommand> toggleAffiliationExclusionsCommand)
    {
        _getAffiliationsQuery = getAffiliationsQuery ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getAffiliationsQuery));
        _toggleAffiliationExclusionsCommand = toggleAffiliationExclusionsCommand ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(toggleAffiliationExclusionsCommand));
    }

    private readonly IQueryHandler<GetAffiliationsQuery, IQueryable<Affiliation>> _getAffiliationsQuery;
    private readonly ICommandHandler<ToggleAffiliationExclusionCommand> _toggleAffiliationExclusionsCommand;

    // Successfully Called
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<PaginationResult<Affiliation>>> GetAffiliations([FromQuery] PaginationModel model)
    {
        var affiliations = await _getAffiliationsQuery.Handle(new GetAffiliationsQuery())                                                            
                                               .PaginateAsync(model.PageIndex,                                                                            
                                                              model.PageSize);
        return affiliations;
    }

    // Not reached via Angular       
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Affiliation>> Foo(int id)
    {
        var target = await _getAffiliationsQuery.Handle(new GetAffiliationsQuery())
                                                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(afn => afn.Id == id);
        if (target == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        await _toggleAffiliationExclusionsCommand.HandleAsync(new ToggleAffiliationExclusionCommand(id));
        return target;
    }

}
```

**Angular Service**

```
export class AffiliationService {
  private readonly apiUrl = 'api/affiliation';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  public get(model: PaginationQuery): Observable<PaginationResult<Affiliation>> {
    // Works just fine
    return this.http
      .get<PaginationResult<Affiliation>>(`${this.apiUrl}`, { params: UtilsService.buildQueryParams(model) })
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  public toggle(affiliation: Affiliation) {
  // Does not work unless I pass the 'id' as a query string parameter instead of a route parameter
    return this.http
      .get(`${this.apiUrl}/${affiliation.id}`)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was:`);
      console.error(error.error);
    }
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

[image: Network Tab]

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

**NG Serve Output**

[image: Nothing for the call to the 'Foo' endpoint]

**Note**

Changing the 'toggle' function to the following is able to successfully reach the endpoint.  But I don't understand why this works over the other way as I can call the endpoint using the route param approach via Postman

```
  public toggle(affiliation: Affiliation) {
    return this.http
      .get(`${this.apiUrl}`, { params: UtilsService.buildQueryParams({ id: affiliation.id }) })
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Comment: i think its in your backend, since you get all the requests and handle it via the client. Did you try to log you http get method? to see if you even enter the function? or it throws before

Comment: The Chrome image shows that the API call is being sent to port 4200, not port 5000 (see line with red GET). No idea unfortunately how to fix that (sub-zero Angular knowledge). Prepending the relative URL with the proper schema+domain+port could help.

Comment: The only output that I'm receiving on the client side is from the "ng serve output" screenshot above.  It's as if the proxy isn't even receiving the call the reroute to port 5000 for the call to the "Foo" endpoint.  @PeterB I'm still relatively new with the proxy functionality provided by angular-cli, but the console output appears to indicate that it's successfully routing the call to port 5000 on the back-end.  I don't have CORS enabled so I'd expect to encounter an error from the first call if it was actually going on port 4200.

Comment: Just to rule out the problem, try change the API routes for both methods to something else completely different (e.g., /api/test1 and /api/test2). I suspected the issue has to do with routing map on the backend side.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a CORS issue.

If you want to fix this without using a plugin, you can use the WebApi Cors package.

If using a C# ASP.NET CORE project:

> Refer to the following page to enable CORS and the request can be
>   called.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1

If using a C# WebAPI project:

Run the following command to install a CORS package for WebApi:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and refer to the following URL for the full microsoft guide:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: For the output of "ng serve" I'm receiving the following from the proxy.  It appears to route the first call successfully, but there's nothing relating to the failed one.   
        [HPM] GET /api/affiliation?pageIndex=1&pageSize=10 -> http://localhost:5000

Comment: The first one I assume belong to zone.js which angular handles, if you look into its response, I am sure you will see nothing that makes sense from your WebApi, if anything at all.
It doesnt really communicate with your server.

Comment: Shouldn't the angular-cli proxy avoid any CORS issue since it's actually routing the request to the correct url?

Comment: From what it looks like the maximum value this could add is to allow the client to attempt addressing any route following "api/".

Please note that your angular project is being run on a node server and in port 5000. While the C# project is being run on iisexpress on a random port. Which is absolutely normal, but it means the client side must communicate server with the full url including correct domain and port.

Comment: Angular project is running on port 4200.  The .Net Core API is running on port 5000

Comment: Does your c# project run on port 5000?

Comment: Yes - the C#/Server side is running on port 5000.  The Angular side is running on port 4200.  I have the proxy for angular-cli setup to route the back-end calls to port 5000 (screenshot added to initial post - ng serve output)

Comment: Is your C# project a WebApi or MVC?

Comment: It is an ASP.NET Core Web Application project. They have merged the functionality of the two project types.  My API controller is inheriting from "ControllerBase" and has the "ApiController" attribute.  If I were writing an MVC controller then I would inherit from the Controller class.

Comment: Refer the following for the correct instructions to enable CORS in your ASP.NET CORE project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: ALSO, as a POC to make sure the C# project is well set, use Chrome REST API  plugin to make this request and make sure the response is good,'. If you do not receive a good response then the problem is in the ASP.NET CORE project

Comment: Please note that if it were more of a CORS issue then I would expect the first call to fail.  It does not and is able to return information successfully.  The extension does not help here and I have verified this.  The purpose of the proxy I'm using with the angular-cli is to bypass any possible CORS issue:  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: I see. Well, if the first API call is indeed returning data (I would make sure by debugging this, not sure if you have), the only thing missing here is the calling function, the one implement the subscribe. Can you add that also?

Comment: I am also not familiar with the params being stated via the [HttpGet("{id}")] attribute.
I know that the same with "Route" attribute works though...